# How to sort the options_for_select hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select

I’ve got something like this:

```
options_for_select({ "1 - optimal" => 1, "2 - ausreichend" => 2, "3 - verbesserungsfähig" => 3, "4 - nicht ausreichend" => 4, "5 - gar nicht" => 5})
```

Rails doesn’t sort these entries on output. How can I achieve the select field to be sorted numerically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe in Ruby1.9, this would work as you intend (hashes preserve their insertion order), so if using 1.9 is an option then you are done.

Otherwise, you can use an array instead of a hash:

```
options_for_select([["1 - optimal", 1], ["2 - ausreichend", 2], ..., ["5 - gar nicht", 5]])
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Except for the forgotten round brackets in your code. Could you please correct this for the afterworld? ;-)